# How to "AUTO FIX" using alter user command?

Tags: sql-server

I was reading [sp_change_users_login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) documentation and it says:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
> Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
> modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER USER
> instead.

How to auto_fix using alter user command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix all orphaned users comparing the user name in [sys.database_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with the login name in [sys.server_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that have mismatched SIDs

```
DECLARE @users NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @users = '';

SELECT @users = @users + 'ALTER USER ' + b.name + ' WITH LOGIN = ' + a.name + ';'
FROM sys.server_principals AS a
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS b
     ON a.name = b.name
WHERE a.sid <> b.sid
      AND b.name <> 'public';

PRINT @users;

EXEC (@users);
```

Comment: Use `STRING_AGG` (or FOR XML PATH pre-SQL 2017) instead of `@users = @users + ...`. The behavior of aggregate string concatenation is otherwise undefined.

Comment: Not sure, but should we exclude 'guest', 'sa', 'dbo', 'public', 'sys' and 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' users? your script only exclude public.

Comment: all of them except sa, are not logins on the instance thus shouldnt match to a name in sys.server_principals. as for sa, if you have created the user sa in the database then yes, you would need to exclude. I dont create sa users specifically as the login already has full permissions to all database.